# Regex in PHP returns not what expected

Tags: php, regex

I am PHP newbie and I hope somebody can help.

There is a site which contains following HTML:

```
<span id="sell_usd_place">1.6640</span>
```

My code is below:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.a_bank.com/currency-rates/');
$regex = "#<span id=\"sell_usd_place\">(.*?)</span>#";
preg_match($regex,$data,$matchKapitalSell);
var_dump($matchKapitalSell);
echo $matchKapitalSell[0]."<br>";
echo $matchKapitalSell[1];
?>
```

What I expect is that in the output I will get:
`"<span id="sell_usd_place">1.6640</span>"`  as it is what I set as a pattern.

Bit what I get is (I am using XAMPP to check the code):

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(39) "1.6640" [1]=> string(6) "1.6640" } 1.6640
1.6640array(0) { }
```

Could anybody explain please:

1. Why I get "1.6640" only and not 
   `<span id="sell_usd_place">1.6640</span>`
2. What is "39" in "string(39)" in above output?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: for parsing xml/html you need use library for build html/xml dom tree, for parsing for example this library https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpquery/

Comment: 1) You only see the rendered/formatted text, 2) `string(39)` = length of `<span id="sell_usd_place">1.6640</span>`. Element 0 is the whole match, and Element 1 is the substring captured with the first `(...)`

Comment: The string(39) means that the string is of length 39. I have a gut feeling that you var_dumped it and looked at in a web browser. Look at the source code. The web browser will hide the HTML tags from you.

Comment: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/476)

Comment: @Naumov  Thank you! I will have a look.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Great Answer! Thank you!

Comment: @kainaw  Thank you! That is great answer!!! I see now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of a regex. Regular expressions aren't fitted to reliably parse HTML.

Example:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.a_bank.com/currency-rates/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$span = $doc->getElementById('sell_usd_place');
$value = $span->nodeValue;

echo $value; # 1.6640
```